# Javascript - Mostrando e ocultando divs de acordo com checkboxes selecionados

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Possuo o site com 9 checkboxes, cada um associado a uma div. Quando um checkbox é selecionado, a div relacionada a ele é mostrada. Quando outro checkbox é selecionado, a div relacionada a esse outro também é mostrada. Por exemplo, chkCamp1 mostra optCamp1. chkCamp2 mostra optCamp2 e "some" com optCamp1, já que o chkCamp1 está deselecionado.

Só que não consigo fazer com que a div da checkbox deselecionada "suma" da tela.

HTML com as nove checkboxes:

```
<input id="chkCamp1" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe('optCamp1', this)">
<input id="chkCamp2" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe('optCamp2', this)">
<input id="chkCamp3" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe('optCamp3', this)">
<input id="chkCamp4" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe('optCamp4', this)">
<input id="chkCamp5" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe('optCamp5', this)">
<input id="chkCamp6" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe('optCamp6', this)">
<input id="chkCamp7" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe('optCamp7', this)">
<input id="chkCamp8" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe('optCamp8', this)">
<input id="chkCamp9" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe('optCamp9', this)">
```

E a função showMe como está no momento.

```
function showMe(it, elem){
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("cb");
        var currentState = elem.checked;
        var elemsLength = elems.length;

        for(i=0; i<elemsLength; i++){
            if(elems[i].type === "checkbox"){
                elems[i].checked = false;   
            }
        }
        elem.checked = currentState;

        if(elem.checked = true){
            document.getElementById(it).style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById(it).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

Como eu posso melhorar isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando somente [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) você iria utilizar a mesma lógica do que foi feito com o checkbox.
Você irá criar uma classe e ocultar todos os elementos. Após isso, irá percorrer todas e verificar se é o id passado. Se for, mostra. Se não for, bloqueia.

Seu código ficará assim

```js
function showMe(it, elem){
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("cb");
  var currentState = elem.checked;
  var elemsLength = elems.length;

  for(i=0; i<elemsLength; i++){
    if(elems[i].type === "checkbox"){
      elems[i].checked = false;   
    }
  }
  elem.checked = currentState;
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ocult');            
  for(j=0; j < elements.length; j++){
    if(elements[j].id != it || currentState == false){
      elements[j].style.display = "none";
    }else{
      elements[j].style.display = "block";
    }
  }         
}
```

```css
.ocult{
    display:none
}
```

```html
<input id="chkCamp1" type="checkbox" class="cb"  onclick="showMe('optCamp1', this)" />1
<input id="chkCamp2" type="checkbox" class="cb"  onclick="showMe('optCamp2', this)" />2
<input id="chkCamp3" type="checkbox" class="cb"  onclick="showMe('optCamp3', this)" />3
<input id="chkCamp4" type="checkbox" class="cb"  onclick="showMe('optCamp4', this)" />4
<input id="chkCamp5" type="checkbox" class="cb"  onclick="showMe('optCamp5', this)" />5
<input id="chkCamp6" type="checkbox" class="cb"  onclick="showMe('optCamp6', this)" />6
<input id="chkCamp7" type="checkbox" class="cb"  onclick="showMe('optCamp7', this)" />7
<input id="chkCamp8" type="checkbox" class="cb"  onclick="showMe('optCamp8', this)" />8
<input id="chkCamp9" type="checkbox" class="cb"  onclick="showMe('optCamp9', this)" />9

<div id="optCamp1" class="ocult">1</div>    
<div id="optCamp2" class="ocult">2</div>    
<div id="optCamp3" class="ocult">3</div>    
<div id="optCamp4" class="ocult">4</div>    
<div id="optCamp5" class="ocult">5</div>    
<div id="optCamp6" class="ocult">6</div>    
<div id="optCamp7" class="ocult">7</div>    
<div id="optCamp8" class="ocult">8</div>    
<div id="optCamp9" class="ocult">9</div>
```

Lembrando que desta forma estou ocultando a `div` via css, assim:

```
.ocult{
    display:none
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!!!

Comment: No exemplo acima, a div não desaparece quando a seleção do checkbox é desfeita.

Comment: @TobyMosque falha minha, eu não havia me atentado à esta situação. Já alterei para atender.

Comment: agora ficou 100%, +1

Answer (score 1):

Gustavo, apesar da Resposta do @Randrade está 100%, gostaria de realizar uma revisão no seu código.

Tente não colocar javaScript e CSS inline no seu HTML, então remova as tags `style` e `onclick`.

Tente agrupar os seus `checkbox` usando a tag `name`, assim fica mais claro que eles devem ter um comportamento semelhante a de um `radio`.

utilize um atributo `data-*` para fazer a associação entre o `checkbox` e o elemento a ser exibido.

Por fim, já que você deve saber qual `checkbox` foi previamente selecionado e qual elemento está sendo exibido, então percorrer todos os `checkbox` é desnecessário, apenas altere as propriedades do mesmo.

Quanto ao markup do HTML abaixo, apenas ignore ele, adicionou os `label` apenas para melhorar o exemplo.

```js
function initChkGroup (chkName) {
  var chkCamps = document.querySelectorAll("[name='" + chkName + "']");
  var chkSel = document.querySelector("[name='" + chkName + "']:checked");
  
  var optSel = null; 
  if (chkSel) {
    optSel = document.getElementById(chkSel.dataset.opt);
    optSel.classList.remove("hidden");
  }

  var onChkCampChange = function (event) {   
    if (chkSel) {
      chkSel.checked = false;
      optSel.classList.add("hidden");
    }
    
    if (event.target.checked) {
      chkSel = event.target;
      optSel = document.getElementById(chkSel.dataset.opt);
      optSel.classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {      
      chkSel = null;
      optSel = null;
    }
  };

  [].forEach.call(chkCamps, function (chkCamp, indice) {
    chkCamp.addEventListener("change", onChkCampChange);
  });  
};

initChkGroup("chkCamp");
```

```css
.cb {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="chkCamp1" type="checkbox" name="chkCamp" class="cb" data-opt="optCamp1" /> 
  <label for="chkCamp1">optCamp1</label>  
</div>
<div>
  <input id="chkCamp2" type="checkbox" name="chkCamp" class="cb" data-opt="optCamp2" /> 
  <label for="chkCamp2">optCamp2</label>  
</div>
<div>
  <input id="chkCamp3" type="checkbox" name="chkCamp" class="cb" data-opt="optCamp3" /> 
  <label for="chkCamp3">optCamp3</label>  
</div>
<div>
  <input id="chkCamp4" type="checkbox" name="chkCamp" class="cb" data-opt="optCamp4" checked /> 
  <label for="chkCamp4">optCamp4</label>  
</div>
<div>
  <input id="chkCamp5" type="checkbox" name="chkCamp" class="cb" data-opt="optCamp5" /> 
  <label for="chkCamp5">optCamp5</label>  
</div>
<div>
  <input id="chkCamp6" type="checkbox" name="chkCamp" class="cb" data-opt="optCamp6" /> 
  <label for="chkCamp6">optCamp6</label>  
</div>
<div>
  <input id="chkCamp7" type="checkbox" name="chkCamp" class="cb" data-opt="optCamp7" /> 
  <label for="chkCamp7">optCamp7</label>  
</div>
<div>
  <input id="chkCamp8" type="checkbox" name="chkCamp" class="cb" data-opt="optCamp8" /> 
  <label for="chkCamp8">optCamp8</label>  
</div>
<div>
  <input id="chkCamp9" type="checkbox" name="chkCamp" class="cb" data-opt="optCamp9" /> 
  <label for="chkCamp9">optCamp9</label>  
</div>

<div id="optCamp1" class="hidden">optCamp1</div>
<div id="optCamp2" class="hidden">optCamp2</div>
<div id="optCamp3" class="hidden">optCamp3</div>
<div id="optCamp4" class="hidden">optCamp4</div>
<div id="optCamp5" class="hidden">optCamp5</div>
<div id="optCamp6" class="hidden">optCamp6</div>
<div id="optCamp7" class="hidden">optCamp7</div>
<div id="optCamp8" class="hidden">optCamp8</div>
<div id="optCamp9" class="hidden">optCamp9</div>
```